# Numpy next element minus previous

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to subtract the next element from current element in a specific axis from numpy array. But, I know how to do that using a lot of loops. My question is: How to do that in the most efficient way? Maybe using numpy?

My Python code below:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

myarr = np.random.rand(20, 7, 11, 151, 161)

newarr = np.full((20, 6, 11, 151, 161), np.nan)

for iyr in range(20):
    for iwk in range(6):
        for imb in range(11):
            for ilat in range(151):
                for ilon in range(161):
                     newarr[iyr, iwk, imb, ilat, ilon] = myarr[iyr, iwk + 1, imb, ilat, ilon] - myarr[iyr, iwk, imb, ilat, ilon]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few good ways of doing this. If you did not care about the last element being NaN, you could use [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

```
myarr = np.random.rand(20, 7, 11, 151, 161)
newarr = np.diff(myarr, axis=1)
```

The result will have shape `(20, 6, 11, 151, 161)`.

If you really want to keep those NaNs, I would recommend using [`np.empty_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html) and [`np.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html). Allocating with [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) is somewhat wasteful since you are definitely setting almost all the elements. The only NaNs you have are in the last index along the second dimension, which you can initialize very cheaply yourself:

```
myarr = np.random.rand(20, 7, 11, 151, 161)
newarr = np.empty_like(myarr)  # Don't repeat shape
newarr[:, -1, ...] = np.nan
np.subtract(myarr[:, 1:, ...], myarr[:, :-1, ...], out=newarr[:, :-1, ...])
```

Since `myarr[:, 1:, ...]`, `myarr[:, :-1, ...]` and `newarr[:, :-1, ...]` are views, this operation avoids temporary arrays and unnecessary initialization almost completely.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy version:

```
myarr = np.random.rand(20, 7, 11, 151, 161)
newarr_np = myarr[:, 1:,] - myarr[:, :-1]
```

Your edited code:

```
from itertools import product

newarr = np.full((20, 6, 11, 151, 161), np.nan)

for iyr, iwk, imb, ilat, ilon in product(range(20), range(6), range(11), range(151), range(161)):
    newarr[iyr, iwk, imb, ilat, ilon] = \
        myarr[iyr, iwk + 1, imb, ilat, ilon] - \
        myarr[iyr, iwk    , imb, ilat, ilon]
```

Equality test

```
np.all(newarr_np == newarr)
> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use array slicing to get a smaller one, add a 0 row/column to that to extend it the same size, and subtract. Like this:

```
>>> x=np.random.rand(10)
>>> x #this is our original array
array([0.49662379, 0.18424862, 0.43346481, 0.57377969, 0.88027509,
       0.9820584 , 0.63669062, 0.27981557, 0.70115255, 0.47660883])
>>> x[1:] #this is the one we want to subtract, but to do that, you need to pad it with zeros
array([0.18424862, 0.43346481, 0.57377969, 0.88027509, 0.9820584 ,
       0.63669062, 0.27981557, 0.70115255, 0.47660883])
>>> ext=np.zeros(1) # so we take a few zeros
>>> ext
array([0.])
>>> np.concatenate((x[1:],ext)) # pad it
array([0.18424862, 0.43346481, 0.57377969, 0.88027509, 0.9820584 ,
       0.63669062, 0.27981557, 0.70115255, 0.47660883, 0.        ])
>>> x-np.concatenate((x[1:],ext)) # and subtract
array([ 0.31237516, -0.24921618, -0.14031489, -0.3064954 , -0.10178331,
        0.34536778,  0.35687505, -0.42133698,  0.22454372,  0.47660883])
```

Of course there could be simpler solutions. You can choose different dimensions, but a 10 long 1D array is good to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:` to select a whole dimension.

```
for iwk in range(6):
    newarr[:,iwk,:,:,:] = myarr[:,iwk+1,:,:,:] - myarr[:,iwk,:,:,:]
```

Comment: You can also use `...` to select one run of contiguous dimensions: `[:, iwk, ...]`